# Can be considered continuous a variable obtained from Principal Component Analysis based on Likert scale?

Tags: pca, ordinal-data, likert

I performed a PCA analysis on a Likert scale with 5 questions which ordinal responses can be 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 (from strongly disagree to strongly agree). I did it in two independent samples. I obtained only one principal component in each group. Now I want to compare the principal component in each group. If my data were continuous, I know that the Principal components are continuous. However, as my Likert scale does not have continuous data (It can't), I would like to know if the resulting principal components should be considered continuous data or something else.

Of course, this is important to determine which test(s) should I use to determine if there is association between the two groups that I want to compare.

Very much thank you,

Nicole

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a linear combination of discrete variables is discrete.

Whether it's reasonable to treat it as if it were continuous will depend. What you may want to avoid would be having any substantive fraction of the distribution focused on only a few possible values. If there was a good spread of values within most of the subscales and they mostly contribute reasonably near to equally (or at least in a way that no subscales very heavily dominate the variance) to that first principal component then you might get a principal component that it would be reasonable to treat as continuous for many different purposes.

Of course, how important that is depends on what you're trying to do with it (some things are pretty sensitive to heavy ties, some things are not) and on what characteristics you need the result to have.

Why do you care if it's reasonable to treat the result as if it were continuous? Why would you need that?

Please note that your question is ambiguous about what you're doing. In the first paragraph you say you're trying to *compare* these principal components, and in the second paragraph you say you want to determine if there is association. Comparison and looking for association are usually quite different aims.

Specifically "compare" would be about looking for differences (or lack of them) in some sense, while association would be looking (presumably in this situation) for some kind of correlation, presumably linear correlation, between pairs of values on the two things.

You might talk about how the two sets of principal components might be related without reference to pairs of data (perhaps by looking at the cosine of the angle between the two components in 6-space), but then it's not really clear what that purpose is. What's the underlying research question (/question of interest) here? What's it all for?

Comment: Dear Glen, very much thank you for your response. Sorry for the inaccuracy, I want to compare both groups. My question is if the results in one group are different from the other groups which were asked for their levels of anxiety. Therefore, I proceeded with the Mann Whitney test. However, as a robustness check I applied the PCA and I ended up with only one relevant component in each group. So my idea is now to compare both component to see if there are significant differences in both groups. So, as I didn't know which type of data the PCA yields, I wasn't sure about which test should I use.

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of comparing the means (or indeed any other location measure) on two different principal components; why would the null be tenable, even on a single group? What would this test tell you?

Comment: It's possible to test this under various sets of assumptions (a two sample t-test that doesn't assume equal variance might work); the problem is whether it makes any sense. Keeping in mind that hypotheses will be about population parameters, what specific hypothesis are you testing? How does it relate to a specific research question?

Comment: Dear Glen, very much thank you for your very helpful responses. My goal is to determine if a group of students of English has more anxiety than other after treatment. So, I have control pre and post test, and experiment pre and post test. However, my samples are not paired, so I can't use dependent sample tests. I had used the Mann Whitney test to compare experiment vs control group pre test, and also to compare experiment vs control group post test. However, I would love to find any other alternative method to determine the robustness of the results obtained by the Mann Whitney tests.

Comment: 1. Do you have pre and post test on the same people within each group? 2. It's not clear what sort of "robustness" you seek. You would not expect very similar results if you're testing a very different hypothesis

Comment: The problem is that I cannot perform tests for paired data because my responses are not paired. The problem started with the collection of the data. Given that problematic issue in my research, I can only compare experiment vs control groups. That is why I would like to support the results obtained by the Mann Whitney test with another test. If that is possible, of course.